Finding a point reflected over the perpendicular line of an angle
I have an angle $\theta$ and a point (x1, y1) which I always have values for.
I am looking to calculate a point (x2, y2) that is the reflection of the point (x1, y1) across the tangent of a line with the angle $\theta$ centered about the origin (technically in my case it's not centered about the origin but I am comfortable shifting things to the origin and back so it doesn't have to be considered for the sake of this question).
In the sketch below, I tried to illustrate this with a black arrow with angle $\theta$, the green dashed line being the tangent line, and the points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) where they would approximately be.
I know I can get the slope of the tangent line from the angle using $m = tan(\theta)$. I also know that the segments between (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) and the origin will have equal lengths (which I called L in the sketch).
However, my geometry skills are failing me to calculate this new reflected point. Any tips on how I can calculate (x2, y2) in this situation?

Here's a diagram of the different possible orientations and what I'm looking to achieve:

Edit: My attempt
Following Andrew's hint, I tried to get the lines' slopes:

The original line's slope: $tan(\theta)$
The tangent line's slope: $tan(\theta + \pi/2)$

Then I tried to write the equation of the tangent line and the line that both $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are on:

The tangent line (with point at $x_0$, $y_0$): $y = \tan\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cdot (x - x_0) + y_0$
The line that $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are on: $y = \tan(\theta) \cdot (x - x_1) + y_1$

Then get the midpoint of side $\overline{(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2)}$:

First, set them equal to each other
Solve for x: $x = \frac{\tan\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cdot x_0 - y_0 + \tan(\theta) \cdot x_1 - y_1}{\tan\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \tan(\theta)}$
Solve for y: $y = \tan(\theta) \cdot \left( \frac{\tan\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cdot x_0 - y_0 + \tan(\theta) \cdot x_1 - y_1}{\tan\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \tan(\theta)} - x_1 \right) + y_1$

Then reflect the original point $(x_1,y_1)$ across that intersection point to get $(x_2,y_2)$:

$x_2 = 2 \cdot \frac{\tan\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cdot x_0 - y_0 + \tan(\theta) \cdot x_1 - y_1}{\tan\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \tan(\theta)} - x_1$
$y_2 = 2 \cdot \tan(\theta) \cdot \left( \frac{\tan\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cdot x_0 - y_0 + \tan(\theta) \cdot x_1 - y_1}{\tan\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \tan(\theta)} - x_1 \right) + y_1 - y_1$

But this doesn't seem to work... What am I doing wrong here?

The perpendicular would be at an angle $\phi=\theta\pm\frac\pi2$.

If $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the angles of the two points, then $${\theta_1+\theta_2\over2}=\theta+{\pi\over2}$$

@Intelligentipauca Thanks, but I'm afraid I don't know how that helps me here

You know $\theta$ and can compute $\theta_1$, hence you can find $\theta_2$ and the coordinates of the second point.

@Intelligentipauca Am I understanding you that this is the situation you're thinking of? Wouldn't $\theta_1 = \theta_2$? I'm still not tracking

No, by $\theta_1$ I mean the angle formed by vector $OP_1$ with $x$-axis: $$\cos\theta_1={x_1\over\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}},\quad\sin\theta_1={y_1\over\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}}.$$ The same for $\theta_2$.

So $\theta_1 = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + y_1^2}}\right)$ and $\theta_2 = 2 \cdot \left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \theta_1$. But I still have 2 unknowns ($x_2$ and $y_2$), right? I'm missing how to get those even if I have the angle

It is not difficult: $$x_2=\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}\cos\theta_2,\quad y_2=\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}\sin\theta_2.$$ Beware that $\cos^{-1}$ won't give you always the right angle. You'd better use the atan2 function available within most programming languages.

@Intelligentipauca That seems to give me a point on the tangent line that's equidistant from the point (x1,y1). I'm instead looking to reflect the point (x1,y1) across the tangent line. Setting $x_2 = x_0 - x_1$ and $y_2 = y_0 - y_1$ seems closer but it fails to factor in the direction of the angle, so it's wrong at least half of the time (at least 1 sign is wrong of the second term when it's wrong)

I tried to clarify my goal by adding an example set of possible orientations and what I'm trying to achieve

Could you give a numeric example where my formulas fail?

@Intelligentipauca Perhaps I have implemented it incorrectly. Here is a video showing what I'm seeing and here's the relevant JS code if you'd like to see what I'm seeing

I need some NUMBERS, not videos or code. Give me $x_1$, $y_1$ and $\theta$ and I'll show you how to compute $x_2$, $y_2$.

How about $x_1 = -1, y_1 = 1, \theta = \pi \cdot 7/4$? That approximates the first diagram I made. The solution should be $x_2 = 1, y_2 = -1$ I believe

OK. I get: $\theta_1=135°$, $\theta=315°$, $\theta_2=675°$, $\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}=\sqrt2$, $x_2=\sqrt2\cos\theta_2=1$, $y_2=\sqrt2\sin\theta_2=-1$.

@Intelligentipauca Thanks, I think it was an issue in my implementation. I will post back here when I get it working the way I want it to be working!

@Intelligentipauca It was an issue with my implementation. It's fixed now! You can see the arms "walking" in the direction of the mouse movement. Now I will need to figure out how to get the arm to not jump so much when first going to the new position but that's a problem for tomorrow. If you'd like to write up your approach in an answer I'm happy to mark it as the answer!
